# React Material-UI:How to disable tooltip after click it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a tab component in Material-UI and I want to implement a tooltip on it.

My problem is that when I click the tab component, the tooltip is not disappearing. It must disappear after I click on that tab.

Currently, it continues to be visible even after I click on the tab.

How do I rectify that?

```
<Tabs
  className="navbar-routes"
  value={value}
  style={{ color: 'green'}}
  indicatorColor="secondary"
  onChange={handleChange} 
>
  {
    tabsData.map(({id,title,description}) => {
      return( 
        <ToolTip description={description}>
          <Tab
            style={{ 
              minWidth: 10,
              fontSize: '80%',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              marginLeft: '-4px',
              marginRight: 4
            }} 
            key={id}
            component={Link}
            to={`/${title}`}
            label={`${title}`}
          />
        </ToolTip>
      );
    }
 )}
  </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the document of Material-UI [tooltip API](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#props)

You would find a props named **disableHoverListener**

> bool
>   default: false
>   Do not respond to hover events.

Set it as `True` would turn off the tooltip onMouseOver event trigger.

---

#### Update

[image]

Or you can simply make it totally under control.

By binding the `onClick`, `onMouseOver`, `onMouseLeave`, `open` to related component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Tooltip, Tab } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [flg, setFlg] = useState(false);
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tooltip
        title={"message"}
        aria-label="add"
        placement="bottom"
        open={!flg && isHover}
      >
        <Tab
          label={`Click: ${!flg ? "enabled" : "disabled"}`}
          onClick={() => setFlg(!flg)}
          onMouseOver={() => setIsHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
        />
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Try it online:

[image: Edit tender-frog-34ekm]

Comment: what about there're multiple tooltips on the same page?

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved this was by rendering the tooltip conditionally. In your case I suppose you want the tooltip not to render for the tab of the current active route:

```
function ConditionalTooltip({renderTooltip, children, ...props}) {

    return renderTooltip ? <Tooltip {...props}>{children}</Tooltip> : children;

}

function Tabs() {
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <Tabs
          className="navbar-routes"
          value={value}
          style={{ color: 'green'}}
          indicatorColor="secondary"
          onChange={handleChange} 
        >
          {
            tabsData.map(({id,title,description}) => {
              return( 
                <ConditionalTooltip 
                    renderTooltip={location.pathname.indexOf(title) === -1} /* only render tooltip on not active urls */
                    title={description}
                >
                  <Tab
                    style={{ 
                      minWidth: 10,
                      fontSize: '80%',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      marginLeft: '-4px',
                      marginRight: 4
                    }} 
                    key={id}
                    component={Link}
                    to={`/${title}`}
                    label={`${title}`}
                  />
                </ConditionalTooltip>
              );
            }
         )}
        </Tabs>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also implement a generic tooltip with a managed state when to open/close the tooltip.

```jsx
import Tooltip, { TooltipProps } from "@mui/material/Tooltip";
import { useState } from "react";

/**
 * MUI Tooltip wrapper with adaption to the move away once focuses left.
 */
export function ManagedTooltip(props: TooltipProps) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

    // Wrap Tooltip with div to capture mouse events
    return <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}
        onMouseEnter={() => setOpen(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setOpen(false)}
        onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
    >
        {/* Show the original MUI Tooltip with all props. */}
        {/* Just override the open attribute to be fully managed, and disable internal listeners */}
        <Tooltip {...props} open={open} disableHoverListener disableFocusListener />
    </div>;
}
```

Once it's ready, you can use it anywhere exactly like the original MUI tooltip.

```
<Tabs
  className="navbar-routes"
  value={value}
  style={{ color: 'green'}}
  indicatorColor="secondary"
  onChange={handleChange} 
>
  {
    tabsData.map(({id,title,description}) => {
      return( 
        <ManagedTooltip description={description}>
          <Tab
            style={{ 
              minWidth: 10,
              fontSize: '80%',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              marginLeft: '-4px',
              marginRight: 4
            }} 
            key={id}
            component={Link}
            to={`/${title}`}
            label={`${title}`}
          />
        </ManagedTooltip>
      );
    }
 )}
  </Tabs>
```